# Typescript : Get object values within an object. Then join() them

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I am working on a project that books jobs from one destination to another, i need to give the user a readable string for the address they will select.

I have a locations api that gets array of objects with addresses and times. The results gives me an object with another object within it. I basically want to get the address object out of the parent object and join the values to a string (minus any values that are null)

I have tried various join() and Object.value() Object.entries() etc. I cannot seem to find the right combination to make this work.

This function is getting the values from my API and setting it into this.locationList.

```
this.bookingService.getAllLocations().pipe(
     finalize(() => {
       **this.locationList = this.bookingStore.locations;**
     })
    ).subscribe(x => {
      this.bookingStore.setLocations(x);
    });
```

and here is the data im getting back from the api call.

```
 0: {id: "52b77b82-478e-4853-b123-db8f4e07878e", name: "Mark", account: "Bio Sci",…}
 account: "Bio Sci"
 address: {buildingName: ""
           companyName: "Oakingham"
           country: "UK"
           county: "Bucks"
           locality: ""
           postCode: "HP11 1AA"
           street: "Street"
           town: "High Wycombe"
  }
 code: "03"
 collectionTimeFrom: "09:00:00"
 collectionTimeTo: "11:00:00"
 deliveryTimeFrom: "11:00:00"
 deliveryTimeTo: "13:00:00"
 id: "52b77b82-478e-4853-b123-db8f4e07878e"
 name: "Mark"
 openingTimeFrom: "09:00:00"
 openingTimeTo: "11:00:00"
```

My desired outcome is to have the address from the API, which is below

```
 address: {
 buildingName: ""
 companyName: "Oakingham"
 country: "UK"
 county: "Bucks"
 locality: ""
 postCode: "HP11 1AA"
 street: "Street"
 town: "High Wycombe"}
```

formatted like the below string, in order and any nulls removed.

Oakingham, Street, High Wycombe, Bucks, HP11 1AA, UK

Comment: How about: `const address: string = \`${addr.companyName}, ${addr.street}, ${addr.town}, ${addr.county}, ${addr.postCode}, ${addr.country}\`` (assumming `addr` is your `address` object)?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the data stored in `locationList` you could do the following:

```
const addr : object = this.locationList.address;

const combinedAddrName: string = [
addr.companyName,
addr.street,
addr.town,
addr.county,
addr.postCode,
addr.country
].filter(x => !!x).join(', ');
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This will unfortunately not ignore empty items, it will leave extra commas in their place. If the county wasn't given, for example, you would get "Oakingham, Street, High Wycombe, , HP11 1AA, UK" (going by the poster's original example).

Comment: Sure, for that you would need additional checks. There is no way to know what the desired format would be if some fields are missing or null/undefined/invalid. The original example is working if I am not mistaken.

Comment: As long as the order remains the same, no matter what items are missing, a filter (like in my answer) solves the problem without individual checks for each possibly missing item.

Comment: I agreed and upvoted. The issue with the commas is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to append all of the non-empty, non-null items together into a string, but it seems that you want the result to come out in a particular order as well (company name first, country last, etc.).

The easy-but-not-in-the-right-order version looks like this:

`Object.keys(addr).map(key => addr[key]).filter(item => !!item).join(', ');`

But since you want a specific order, you should define an array of keys with that order, with the caveat that any key not listed, even if that key appears in the address object, it will be ignored:

```
// Put buildingName and locality wherever they should go
const keys = ['companyName', 'street', 'town', 'county', 'postCode', 'country']; 
keys.map(key => addr[key]).filter(item => !!item).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string object and just concat all the parts together to create one string with desire format.

Something like

```
this.bookingService.getAllLocations().pipe(
 finalize(() => {
   this.locationList = this.bookingStore.locations;
 })
).subscribe(x => {
  let addrStr = x.address.companyName + ", " + x.address.street + ", " x.address.town + ", " x.address.county + ", " x.address.postCode + ", " x.address.country;
  this.bookingStore.setLocations(addrStr);
});
```

Comment: This will unfortunately not ignore empty items, it will leave extra commas in their place. If the county wasn't given, for example, you would get "Oakingham, Street, High Wycombe, , HP11 1AA, UK" (going by the poster's original example).

Comment: That is true, so if he wants to retain the format. OP might need to add if statements  

`let addrStr = "";  
if(x.address.companyName) addrStr.concat(x.address.companyName + ", ");  
if(x.address.street) addrStr.concat(x.address.street+ ", ");  
...  
...`